# A good way to organize a code involving const references with limited scope and templates in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, reference, auto

So, I have the following piece of code:

```
if (some_boolean_statement)
{
    const auto& ref = getRef<TYPE_A>(); //getRef returns TYPE_A
    doStuff(ref);
}
else
{
    const auto& ref = getRef<TYPE_B>(); //getRef returns TYPE_B
    doStuff(ref);
}
```

So, I want to obtain a constant reference `ref` which depending on `some_boolean_statement` being `true` or `false` is either of `TYPE_A` or `TYPE_B`.
After that, no matter what, I will call an overloaded function `doStuff()` that can accept both types as an input.

Notes:

- `getRef<TYPE_A>()` and `getRef<TYPE_B>()` are operating on different data and are pretty much unrelated
- `some_boolean_statement` is run-time

Now, I don't like that I have to write `doStuff(ref);` in both branches of the if statement. But since the scope of `ref` is limited, I don't see a clear way to do it.

Am I missing something really simple? Any advice?

Comment: Is there any relationship between the type of the first call and the second?

Comment: @Rakete1111 `getRef` is a templated function that will spill either an object of `TYPE_A` or `TYPE_B`. Depending on the <TYPE>, it will do very different things that are not related.

Comment: @Jarod42 unfortunately, no.

Comment: So what is not good with this code? If both branches operate on different types and perform a different jobs then I don't see much of a problem here. typing `doStuff` twice does not look like a sufficient reason to build up some templates (invoking which would probably require about the same amount of typing).

Comment: @VTT twice - comes only because I simplified the logic a bit. There are many more `TYPES` (even in the nested fashion) -> thus, many more retyping of the same `doStuff`.

Comment: Get rid of `ref` variable :) `if (cond) {doStuff(getRef<TYPE_A>()); } else { doStuff(getRef<TYPE_B>());}` ?

Comment: So is this an oversimplified example and you actually have a switch or something? I guess you should post extended example. That would be a different matter.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `std::variant` and `std::visit`.

Comment: @VTT right now it is written as multiple folded `if` statements (just because). However, it can be reorganized as a switch with about 8 cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert control flow and a runtime to compile time dispatcher.

This is insanely complex in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), and modestly complex in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14).

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) you can get:

```
pick( some_boolean_statement,
  &getRef<TYPE_A>,
  &getRef<TYPE_B>
)([&](auto* getRef){
  const auto& ref = getRef();
  doStuff(ref);
});
```

but basically every step along that way is a pain in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

Another approach would be to make a std ([c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)) or boost ([c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03)) variant that stores a pointer to `TYPE_A` or `TYPE_B`.  Then use `visit`; but even here, you'd need an auto lambda to keep your code short.

The simplest [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) version is:

```
auto doWork = [&](const auto& ref) {
  doStuff(ref);
};
if (some_boolean_statement) {
  doWork(getRef<TYPE_A>());
} else {
  doWork(getRef<TYPE_B>());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `some_boolean_statement` is evaluated at run time, there is no avoiding the `if-else` part of the code.

The least amount of code you must have in each branch of the `if` statement is one statement. The best you can do is write other functions or function templates to minimize the amount of code in the two branches.

You could use

```
if (some_boolean_statement)
{
   doStuff<TYPE_A>();
}
else
{
   doStuff<TYPE_B>();
}
```

where

```
template <typename T> void doStuff()
{
   doStuff(getRef<T>());
}
```

I don't see how you can do any better than this. Besides, if this is the greatest problem in your code, you code is good in shape.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write a switch-like dispatcher class that maps condition value to target type and accepts action to be performed only once so the usage would be similar to this:

```
 Switch<Action, bool, Case<true, TYPE_A>, Case<false, TYPE_B>>(some_boolean_statement);
```

Proof-of-concept implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

template<auto cond, typename x_Target> struct
Case;

template<template<typename T> class x_Action, typename x_Cond, typename... x_Case>
class DispatchImpl;

template<template<typename T> class x_Action, typename x_Cond, x_Cond this_cond, typename x_Target, typename... x_Case>
class DispatchImpl<x_Action, x_Cond, Case<this_cond, x_Target>, x_Case...>
{
    public: static void Dispatch(x_Cond cond)
    {
        if(this_cond == cond)
        {
            x_Action<x_Target>::Invoke();
        }
        else
        {
            DispatchImpl<x_Action, x_Cond, x_Case...>::Dispatch(cond);
        }
    }
};

template<template<typename T> class x_Action, typename x_Cond>
class DispatchImpl<x_Action, x_Cond>
{
    public: static void Dispatch(x_Cond) {}
};

template<template<typename T> class x_Action, typename x_Cond, typename... x_Case>
void Switch(x_Cond cond)
{
    DispatchImpl<x_Action, x_Cond, x_Case...>::Dispatch(cond);
}

//
template<typename T> auto getRef(void) { return T{}; }
void doStuff(int) { ::std::cout << "int" << ::std::endl; }
void doStuff(float) { ::std::cout << "float" << ::std::endl; }

template<typename x_Target> struct
Action
{
    static void Invoke(void)
    {
        doStuff(getRef<x_Target>());
    } 
};

int main()
{
   auto cond{false};
   Switch<Action, bool, Case<true, int>, Case<false, float>>(cond);
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EbrdSjkqympYa6sw)